# How to open 2 windows of File/Projects explorer in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide

Is there a way to have 2 windows of files/projects open in netbeans? I want to have one of these windows pointed at one folder, and the other window pointed at another folder. When you have a lot of files and have to constantly switch between the two folders, it gets annoying to have to scroll that much each time.

Comment: +1 If you ever find the solution to this, please do share the with the rest of us. Thanks.

Comment: @Joraid Just open one 'Project' and one 'Files' window, like the answer below describes.

Comment: @Joraid Check my answer it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't found a way to have 2 project windows open but I have stacked a project and a file window in the same pane. Just open both windows and drag one down to half size. Also you can undock (float) the windows and put them where ever you want.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, works but sucks. They should add a way to open as many windows as needed, that's the whole point of OOP.

Answer (score 2):

No exist solutions. But you can "hack" like this: https://pandazen.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/open-netbeans-with-two-instances-windows-simultaneously/

Answer (score 2):

The instructions provided in [opening-multiple-netbeans-ide-instances](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2008/12/opening-multiple-netbeans-ide-instances.html) actually works.

I have tested it and working as expected. You need to create shortcut for tow different directories with providing project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Two open two instances of Netbeans, I double click on two program files in quick succession before Netbeans can fire itself up.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to explicitly add in here the "hack" mentioned by @Do_Nhu_Vy  (since I don't trust third party websites, and I don't have enough *reputation* to reply to his comment). All credit goes to the original WordPress user (Pandazen) in said link.

Now then,

the hack/solution consists of changing the "userdir" of NetBeans at launch time: when NetBeans detects a different "userdir" (than the already opened Netbeans' window) it will then proceed to open a new window.

The process of changing NetBeans' *userdir* at launch is simple:

1. Create an empty user directory, for example:

   ```
   C:\tmp
   ```
2. Duplicate your already existing NetBeans shortcut (create a new one). You'll most likely find the shortcut in the "Start Menu" Windows directory

   ```
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\NetBeans"
   ```
3. Right click the newly created Netbeans shortcut and choose "Properties",
4. Modify the "Target" field by adding the *--userdir DIRECTORY* suffix with the chosen path, replacing **DIRECTORY** with your newly created empty directory. For example:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans64.exe"" --userdir C:\tmp
   ```

Now, every shortcut will launch a NetBeans instance in a different window. This works with NetBeans 8.2, but I haven't tested it with NetBeans 9 or 10.